# Doctrine ORM multi-valued properties

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm

How can I map a class with multi-valued properties using Doctrine ORM? For example, I have a `Person` class with a `mail` property which is an array of strings:

```
class Person {
    protected $mail;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->mail = array('first@example.com', 'second@example.com');
    }
}
```

The dimension of the array is non-predictable. There are other ways besides creating a new object to represent the e-mail address string?

Answer (score 0):

Won't the doctrine "Array" datatype suffice?

This will create a text field in your DB, and the array will automatically be serialized by the ORM when you flush.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html

Comment: Hm, would it be searchable? I mean, how to query a serialized value?

Comment: Not cheaply it wouldn't. If you want it to be I'd advise using a OneToMany relation to an Email entity.